# Angular 12 - returns loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngfor

I'm getting data from api as object. I'm trying to use in component.html with ngFor but I'm getting this error

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'test'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays**.

So my object like this:

*{id: 9, name: 'test', username: 'testmg', email: 'test@gmail.com', email_verified_at: null, …}*

How can I solve this?

**profile.component.ts**

```
  username:any
  playerData:any

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.username = this.router.snapshot.params.username
    this.getOne()
  }


  getOne(){
    this.dataService.getProfile(this.username).subscribe(res=>{
      this.playerData = res
    })
  }
```

**profile.component.html**

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of playerData">
     {{item}}
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you expect in `{{item}}` `9, est@gmail.com...`?

Comment: actually if i type `{{item.id}}` i want to see value of id or if i type `{{item.name}}` i want to see value of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap object in the array using [RxJs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) map before assigning response to `this.playerData`, No change is needed in the template.

```
this.dataService.getProfile(this.username).pipe(
 map(resp => [resp])
).subscribe(res=>{
  this.playerData = res;
}
```

**Some code optimization:**

Declare `playerData` as

```
playerData$: Observable<any[]>;
```

Bind API response to `playerData$`

```
this.playerData$ = this.dataService.getProfile(this.username).pipe(
    map(resp => [resp])
);
```

In template use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) which will subscribe and unsubscribe for us:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of playerData$ | async">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

This way you do not need to take care of subscribing and unsubscribing to Observable.

Imports used

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean *solve*? The message is self-explanatory: you have an object `playerData`; and you can't `*ngFor` on an object!

if you want to traverse the properties of the object you can do something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Object.Keys(playerData)">
   {{item}} : {{playerData[item]}}
</div>
```

as example